# Sprite Kit Grow Physics Body

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to simulate a slow explosion, so I want the hit box of something to grow.

Is there a way of growing the hitbox to a set value, or do I have to manually resize the physics body?

Currently I set the size of the hitbox like this:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_radius];
```

But I would like the physics body to grow from nothing to the full size within a fixed time interval (i.e. 1 second).

Answer (score 2):

Resizing physics bodies is not supported. You can only create a new body with a slightly larger size for a couple of frames. However this isn't exactly efficient.

Since this is a circle body you can do manual hit testing using regular trigonometry. Test each potential contact candidate for distance to the explosion center.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing a node's xScale and yScale seems to modify the size of its physicsBody accordingly.

However, any collisions that result due to this scaling receive no corresponding impulses — there is no "scaling" velocity to "transfer" to any bodies touched by the "explosion". The explosive will push the bodies out of the way, but once it stops changing, the contacted bodies will have no additional velocity. This may or may not be what you want.

To expand on this, you could modify the collisionBitMasks and contactBitMasks so the explosion only triggers contact events and not collision resolution. Then, use didBeginContact() to identify when and where a collision occurs and apply an impulse to the contacted body as desired.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, an [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) (radialGravityField) might provide an alternate approach all together.